# In Lua, can I easily select the Nth result without custom functions?

Tags: string, lua, gsub, lua-table, lua-patterns

Suppose I am inserting a string into a table as follows:

```
table.insert(tbl, mystring)
```

and that `mystring` is generated by replacing all occurrences of "a" with "b" in `input`:

```
mystring = string.gsub(input, "a", "b")
```

The obvious way to combine the two into one statement doesn't work, because `gsub` returns two results:

```
table.insert(tbl, string.gsub(input, "a", "b"))  -- error!
-- (second result of gsub is passed into table.insert)
```

which, I suppose, is the price paid for supporting multiple return values. The question is, is there a standard, built-in way to select just the first return value? When I found `select` I thought that was exactly what it did, but alas, it actually selects *all* results from N onwards, and so doesn't help in this scenario.

Now I know I can define my own `select` as follows:

```
function select1(n, ...)
  return arg[n]
end

table.insert(tbl, select1(1, string.gsub(input, "a", "b")))
```

but this doesn't look right, since I'd expect a built-in way of doing this.

So, am I missing some built-in construct? If not, do Lua developers tend to use a separate variable to extract the correct argument or write their own `select1` functions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can surround the expression by parentheses:

```
table.insert(tbl, (string.gsub(input, "a", "b")))
```

This will select only the first result.

To get the nth result, you can use `select` and surround it by parentheses:

```
func1( (select(n, func2())) )
```

Comment: Thanks! I bet I will eventually run into the same situation wanting only the _second_ result - what options do I have then?

Comment: @romkyns: Updated my post to answer. Though your `select1` function may be more readable.

Comment: I like to use dummies for this, i.e. `_,_,_,fourthVal,_ = giveMeFive()` I find it more readable that way.

Comment: @fbcocq: Yes, but the question for for an alternative way to that: It specifically asked how to avoid the assignment and do it in one statement. Also, `select` is needed when the value of `n` isn't known in advance.

Comment: `surround it by parentheses` why is that needed?

Comment: @Mvorisek Surrounding a function call that returns multiple values by parentheses will choose only the first returned result. If you're asking about the `select` call, the parentheses are needed because `select` returns multiple values.

Answer (score 6):

In one line: `({ funct(args) })[n]` would return the n'th result without declaring any named variables.

Answer (score 5):

Putting an expression into parentheses like this:

`table.insert(tbl, (string.gsub(input, "a", "b")))`

will force one return value. Or you could catch them both like this:

```
str,cnt = string.gsub(input, "a", "b")
table.insert(tbl, str)
```

or even better, dummy catch it to save a variable:

```
str,_ = string.gsub(input, "a", "b")
table.insert(tbl, str)
```

Comment: There is no reason to assign into two variables here. You can just assign one variable and the second value will be discarded, as shown in the beginning of the question.

Comment: Just demonstrating a way to deal with multiple return values besides select, it's sometimes hard to keep track of return value adjustments in huge nested calls.