# Pre-process ... input - bad argument #2 to 'format' (no value)

Tags: lua, lua-table, lua-5.1

I've got a scenario where I want to take input to a printf implementation and pre-process the arguments. My goal is to take the input, process the variable arguments (`...`) if necessary, and feed that into a string.format. The issue I'm encountering is the data gets "lost" when passing it around. I'm finding nil values in `...` are not passed in. For example, if the normal run passes `nil, false, false`, subsequent downline functions in the call path only see `false, false`.  What am I missing here to get the keep the data preserved when converted to an internal table (`{...}`) for processing?

EDIT: I was incorrect in my initial assessment. nil is never preserved (even in printf). If `...` is printed, the table can be empty (for all nil) or only have indexed values in the places that contain "real" data (e.g. TablePrint gives { [2] = false, [3] = false })

This *is* running inside a game, but I can replicate the behavior without using any of the game data.

```
local function TablePrint (data, indent)
    if not indent then indent = 0 end

    local output = string.rep(" ", indent) .. "{\r\n"
    indent = indent + 2
    
    for k, v in pairs(data) do
        output = output .. string.rep(" ", indent)
        
        if (type(k) == "number") then
            output = output .. "[" .. k .. "] = "
        elseif (type(k) == "string") then
            output = output  .. k ..  "= "   
        end
        
        if (v == nil) then
            output = output .. 'nil' .. ",\r\n"
        elseif (v == NULL) then
            output = output .. 'NULL' .. ",\r\n"
        elseif (type(v) == "number") then
            output = output .. v .. ",\r\n"
        elseif (type(v) == "string") then
            output = output .. "\"" .. v .. "\",\r\n"
        elseif (type(v) == "table") then
            output = output .. TablePrint(v, indent + 2) .. ",\r\n"
        else
            output = output .. "\"" .. tostring(v) .. "\",\r\n"
        end
    end
    
    output = output .. string.rep(" ", indent-2) .. "}"
    
    return output
end

local function NormalizeValue(v)
    local output

    if (v == nil) then
        output = 'nil'
    elseif (v == NULL) then
        output = 'NULL'
    elseif (type(v) == "number" or type(v) == "string") then
        output = v
    elseif (type(v) == "table") then
        output = TablePrint(v)
    else
        output = tostring(v)
    end

    return output
end

local function NormalizeArgs(...)
    local args = {...}
    --print(TablePrint(args))
    local normalizedArgs = {}

    for _,v in ipairs(args) do
        table.insert(normalizedArgs, NormalizeValue(v))
    end

    return unpack(normalizedArgs)
end

local function printf(message, ...)
    --print(TablePrint({...}))
    local output

    if (type(message) == "number") then
        output = message
    elseif (type(message) == "string") then
        output = string.format(message, NormalizeArgs(...))
        --this call to string.format succeeds if used
        --output = string.format(message, ...)
    elseif (type(message) == "table") then
        output = TablePrint(message)
    else
        output = tostring(message)
    end

    print(output)
end

--this line fails since nil isn't preserved across call boundaries
--printf('initial conditions, cursor: %s, confirm window: %s, isfinished: %s', nil, nil, nil)
--this line fails since nil isn't preserved across call boundaries
printf('initial conditions, cursor: %s, confirm window: %s, isfinished: %s', nil, false, false)
--this will succeed
printf('initial conditions, cursor: %s, confirm window: %s, isfinished: %s', false, false, false)
--in the normal impl the final parameter is supplied by a call to a local function
printf('initial conditions, cursor: %s, confirm window: %s, isfinished: %s', gamelib.Cursor.ID(), gamelib.Window('Confirm').Open(), nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [select](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-select) to fully examine `...`. It's probably easier to return multiple values recursively than to create a table just to unpack it:

```
local function NormalizeArgs(...)
    if select('#', ...) > 0 then
        return NormalizeValue(select(1, ...)), NormalizeArgs(select(2, ...))
    end
end
```

Comment: Based on this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2704798/3510892, I learned I had to add parentheses around the select to get the individual value. But this answer got me close enough to make it work.

Comment: No, the first value from `select` is there regardless. `NormalizeValue` has no optional parameters that could get messed up by the extra values.